# Modelling resource selection in savanna ungulates

Tags: generalized-linear-model, maximum-likelihood, methodology, ecology

I am amidst an analysis of an 8 year data set that was collected from wildlife surveys over an 8 year period for my MSc thesis. 2 surveys were conducted each season for the three discernible seasons in the region. During these surveys, all ungulate species and their perpendicular distance to the survey trail were recorded, with group sizes if in herds. In 2014, 260 vegetation plots were made at 2km intervals along the entire survey trail with percentage cover of each tree species. These were organised into assemblages by association using a neural network analysis. I have also extracted a number of other environmental variables such as distance to water/towns, NDVI (greeness of vegetation) etc. for each of the plots.

As direction (left or right) from the survey trail for each ungulate observation was not recorded I can't project the recorded GPS points to their exact locations. Thus I created polygons but cutting the survey trail into 1km segments centered on the veg plots, giving each polygon the values for the environmental variables at that location. So each polygon has just one value for each covariate (unless it changes with time like NDVI). I then "selected" all observations within each polygon over all years and gave it the same covariate values as the polygon.

The main questions I want to answer for this data set are:

1. How does ungulate detection vary for each plot and each survey
2. What were the yearly abundances for each species
3. What resources does each species select for/against (using a resource selection function)

I have begun answering the first 2 questions using distance sampling. Where a maximum likelihood  curve is fitted to the observation distances (assuming 100% chance of observation at distance 0) that should decrease (monotonically) in detection probability with greater distances. By grouping the distances into bins we can then estimate the probability of detection for all observations within that bin. I then divide the original count value by the detection probability at its respective distance to get a "true" count value.

I want to now run a GLM to capture resource selection. That is, predict the proportion of use for any environmental resource against what is available. Put simply, the data set going into the model has 40 (8 years x 6 surveys per year) survey events at each plot. 1 row for each survey. If ungulates were seen the count values are pooled together for that survey, if no observations are made then the plot receives a 0. Thus modelling counts against any of the covariates should estimate ungulate count trends for that covariate. With a step AIC selection process allowing me to find the best fit.

However, I know from my detection function that detectability was far from perfect. I want to be able to account for this in my resource selection model in someway but have not found a statistically sound method as yet. My current method involves using the predict function (for my distance detection function) to estimate detectability for each observation in the data set. I then divide the original count value by this value to an adjusted count value. I then and run my model on these new values. I am aware that all models give estimates with a confidence interval, which is why I create two adjusted count columns instead of the mean, one for high and low standard error. I run my resource selection models on both to see if any changes in trends occur.

I have found no literature describing this method which is unnerving, further more my professor refers to it as "stats on stats" but we both seem at the end of our wits on how to move forward.

My question finally is, how statistically sound is this method and are there more statistically sound ways of doing this? For example, incorporating detectability of ungulates directly into my resource selection model? OR Are there other approaches to accounting for detectability outside of the Distance package that will help me avoid doing stats on stats?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: you might want to try this question on the `r-sig-ecology@r-project.org` mailing list ...

Comment: @BenBolker thank you, I realised it was out of place but didn't know a more suitable platform...until now

Comment: It's not a bad question, it's just (1) somewhat specialized (although there a few ecological statisticians on here) and (2) a lot at once (most CV questions are slightly more bite-sized chunks).  When/if you post to `r-sig-ecology` you should probably mention that you've tried here/link to this question

Comment: Ben is right; typically a many-part question will be marked as too broad. If there's parts that split off easily you might consider doing so.